# string search and replacing trouble in python

Tags: python-3.x

currently Iam trying to open a txt file (which works), search something with wildcards and replace the line with parts of the found expression.

The line itself looks like this:
CreateDate="20170505101257000"

Because the date changes, I just want to search a line which contains:
CreateDate

If CreateDate is found, this line should be replaced with:
Print Date : 170505

As you see, the date code should be changed from 20170505101257000 to 170505 in this case. Skip the first 2 and the last 9 digits

my current code can only search the exact match and replace it with something fixed (see below). I read about regex, but my py knowledge is limited, since i am a beginner. So I need your help to change my code.

```
import sys

path = r'C:\temp\test.txt'
fh = open((path), 'r')
Lines = fh.readlines()
fh.close()
fh = open((path), 'w')

for Line in Lines:
  if Line.find('CreateDate="20170505101257000"') >= 0:
    Line = Line.replace('CreateDate="20170505101257000"', 'test')
    fh.write(Line)
  else:
    fh.write(Line)

fh.close()
```

Comment: `fh.seek(0)
fh.truncate()` is unneccesary when opening in `w` BTW.

Comment: OK, thanks. Changed. now we can focus on the main topic.

Comment: anybody able to help, please?